# Validate if cell value is in a array

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a code to do something if the cell value of my range is not in the array. the problem I get is when the cell value is in the array but not = the i of my for each its switch to "you're out"

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Validation").Range("B4:B62")
Dim cell As Range
Dim arrCsAng As Variant
Dim element As Variant
Dim i

arrCsAng = Array("881", "882", "883", "884", "885", "886", "889") 

 For Each cell In rng

     For i = LBound(arrCsAng) To UBound(arrCsAng)

        If arrCsAng(i) = cell.Value Then

            Debug.Print cell.Value & " You're in so do nothing"
            Exit For

        Else

            Debug.Print cell.Value & " You're out so do something"

        End If

    Next i

 Next
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not immediately clear what you you need help with. What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Ok sorry if it is not clear. The problem is if  the cell value is in my array like "889" for exemple and the for each of the range is on "881" who is also in my array i get "you're out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem that even if a cell is found in the array, you get several "Outs" before you get to the "In"?

You can avoid that (and two loops) by using `Match`.

Your final objective is not clear to me so have left that open.

```
Sub x()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Validation").Range("B4:B62")
Dim cell As Range
Dim arrCsAng As Variant
Dim i As Long

arrCsAng = Array("881", "882", "883", "884", "885", "886", "889")   'probably don't need "" as these are numbers

For Each cell In rng
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(cell.Value, arrCsAng, 0)) Then   'cell is found
        Debug.Print cell.Value & " You're in so do nothing"
    Else                                                            'cell not in array
        Debug.Print cell.Value & " You're out so do something"      
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: That's it! you nail it! it works perfectly! Thank you and sorry for the unclear part

Answer (score 0):

A separate boolean function is needed, which loops on its own, checking whether the value is in the given array:

```
Public Function ValueInArray(myValue As Variant, myArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim myVar As Variant
    For Each myVar In myArray
        If myVar = myValue Then
            ValueInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next myVar

    ValueInArray = False

End Function
```

Then this would work nicely:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A5")

    myRange(1) = 20
    myRange(2) = 300
    myRange(3) = 200
    myRange(4) = 50
    myRange(5) = 150

    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In myRange
        If ValueInArray(myCell.Value, myArray) Then
            Debug.Print myCell.Value; " is in array!"
        Else
            Debug.Print myCell.Value; " is NOT in array!"
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

providing results once:

[image]